# Make border width a half of its parent's height element using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-shapes

Here is I want to do:

[image: outerDiv and innerDiv]

I'm making an shape(triangle) using css border property with 0px height & width. The shape should be same height as its parent. It's parent height is unknown and varying. How can this accomplish with the use of css.(without using Javascript)

I also tried to use percentages ( border-width: 50%; )

Here is the code but it is not required!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        body > div {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            width: 400px;
            height: 70px;/* unknownHeight = 70px */
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .shape {

            border-width: 35px; /* unknownHeight/2 = 35px */
            border-style: solid;

            border-top-color: transparent;
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: red;
            border-left-color: red;
        }
        .stableDiv {
            flex: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div class="stableDiv"></div>
        <div class="shape"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) prior to posting. It is expected that you at least try and provide some code.

Comment: Essentialy, you can't. There is no CSS mechanism to relate `width` to `height`. You can do it the other way round but not that way.

Comment: does width also need to be resized or does the triangle can stretch ? Else a pseudo and linear-gradient will be efficient enough to draw that shape. If angle needs to be kept at 45deg, soon it will fill entire box growing up ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned any code. I can suggest you to visit the below links for generating triangle using CSS.

http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: making triangle is not the problem. The problem is making is same height as is parent(which is unknown). Can u help #Yashwardhan_Pauranik

Answer (score 0):

Essentialy, you can't do this with borders or standard HTML elements as yhere is no CSS mechanism to relate an element's width to height.

However, you could use a positioned **square SVG with a triangle polygon**.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}

.taller {
  height: 100px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

svg polygon {
  fill: red;
}

div:hover polygon {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="taller">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can draw a triangle using css border property:

```css
#shape {
  border-width: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjpen5at/1/

Not sure if that answers your question since it wasn't clear.